# Carregar módulos em um só arquivo diminui o desempenho do app?

Tags: node.js

Meu projeto tem vários módulos, se eu carregar todos eles em um arquivo - modulos.js - , estou diminuindo o desempenho do app? ex:

arquivo que carrega módulos (modulos.js):

```
 exports.var1 = require("...")
 exports.var2 = require("...")
```

Arquivo 1:

```
    modulos = require(modulos.js)

    modulos.var1.funcao()
    modulos.var2.funcao()
```

Arquivo 2:

```
   modulos = require(modulos.js)
   modulos.var1.funcao()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carregar todos os módulos num ficheiro ou carregar em cada módulo parece-me irrelevante.

O Node.js coloca em memória cada módulo carregado e não volta a carregar o módulo se for pedido outra vez. Caso haja *N* ficheiros que precisem de um módulo ele serve-o de memória.

Aconselho mesmo a que cada ficheiro faça require dos módulos que precisa, no inicio do ficheiro. Assim cada módulo fica mais estanque e se for preciso removê-lo ou usá-lo noutro sítio é mais fácil controlar as suas reais dependências.